# ES6 - declare a prototype method on a class with an import statement

Tags: javascript, class, import, prototype, ecmascript-6

I am using ES6 classes. I want to be able to do this:

```
function Car(color) {
  this.color = color;
};

Car.prototype.getColor = require('./getColor');
```

Where get color is an exported function. i.e. I want to be able to import a function from an outside file and set is as a prototype method on the ES6 Class. This is the kind of syntax I am talking about:

```
class Car {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

  getColor() {} // I want to import this function from './getColor', as above
}
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can still attach a method on a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)' prototype; after-all, classes are just syntactic sugar over a "functional object", which is the old way of using a function to construct objects.

Since you want to use ES6, I'll use an ES6 import.

#### Minimal effort, using the prototype:

```
import getColor from 'path/to/module';

class Car {
    ...
}

Car.prototype.getColor = getColor;
```

As you can see, you still use the prototype property to attach a method, should you choose to.

---

#### Calling the module within a class' method:

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the prototype property, you can always have your method return the function from the module:

```
import getColor from 'path/to/module';

class Car {
    getColor () {
        return getColor.call(this);
    }
}
```

---

#### Using a Getter

You could also be a bit tricky and use a "getter" to achieve this in a different manner.

```
import getColor from 'path/to/module';

class Car {
    get getColor () { return getColor.bind(this) }
}
```

You could then use it simply by calling, `myInstanceOfCar.getColor()`

Or in a more semantic usage of a getter:

```
class Car {
    get color () { return getColor.call(this) }
}

// ...

const color = myInstanceOfCar.color;
```

Keep in mind that getters/setters cannot have the same name as properties that you set in the constructor. You will end up exceeding the maximum call-stack with infinite recursion when you try to use the setter to set that same property. **Example: `set foo (value) { this.foo = value }`**

---

#### ES2016 Class Properties

If you're [using Babel to transpile](https://babeljs.io/) (and are [using experimental proposals](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/)), and want to use some [ES2016, you can use the following syntax](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-properties) (but keep in mind that this applies the method to the object directly, and does not set it on the prototype):

```
import getColor from 'path/to/module';

class Car {
    getColor = getColor;
}
```

---

#### Optional binding w/ class properties

If you use the shorthand syntax for setting a property, **you won't have to bind the method** (setting is as a property changes what "this" refers to, essentially automatically binding it), but you certainly can, should you choose to (like if you'd like to bind something else):

```
getColor = getColor.bind(this);
```

Comment: No, you don't need to bind the function. It's still the method invocation that sets `this`.

Comment: For anyone who is running into binding issues with adding to the prototype, these must be regular `function` declarations. Meaning you cannot be using imported arrow functions.

Comment: @GoogleMac It's because of this that I personally believe that arrows should be reserved for callbacks, where the lexical binding actually makes sense. Standalone `function` declarations should be used everywhere else (but this is just my personal preference)

Comment: And if I'd like to add methods to standard classes like String? I'd like to import a file and then - preferably without any more code - have String extended with my additional methods. Thanks!

Comment: Silly me. Just import './stringextender.js' - and it works

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The `class` syntax is just (very sophisticated) syntactic sugar for constructor functions. So `Car` will still be a function with a `prototype` property and you can do exactly the same:

```
import getColor from './getColor';
// ...
Car.prototype.getColor = getColor;
```

However, that makes the method enumerable, as opposed to the methods created from the class syntax. So you might want to use `Object.defineProperty` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that I can do this. I probably didn't make clear from the question that I wish to maintain the new syntax for imports in ES6, and also the ES6 classes way of declaring a prototype method (as above). Is that possible?

Comment: FWIW, I only used `require` here for simplicity. Nothing prevents you from using `import` to get the value. As for the class syntax, no, ES6 does not provide a way to do that (except workarounds that delegate to the function as shown in the other answer). There is an [ES7 stage 0 proposal](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-properties) for class properties, where you can write `class Foo { getColor = require('./getColor'); }`, but again, there is nothing like that in ES6.

Comment: @SheedySheedySheedy If you want an ES6 import, see my answer. Imports are hoisted, though, so you have to declare them at the very top.

Comment: I am wondering, why are then the static methods. Is it not their purpose to superset the prototype (not working on the instance) methods hm...

Comment: @FelixKling  this solution is not working in react please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603632/how-to-separate-jsx-inside-render-function-into-a-separate-file-in-es6-or-any-o

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested, I've developed a little module to bind functions with various number of parameters to class methods: https://github.com/ngryman/to-method.

```
const toMethod = require('to-method');

function Car(color) {
  this.color = color;
}

toMethod(Car, { getColor: require('./getColor') });
```