# How to Separate Jsx inside render function into a separate file in ES6? or any other solution in react to separate the Logic and presentation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

Here is the code in ES5 in which the jsx is written into a separate file

```
import React from 'react';
import Template from './template.jsx';

const DetailElement = React.createClass({
  render: Template
});

export default DetailElement;
enter code here
```

template.jsx file will be like this

```
import React from 'react';

const render = function() {

    return (
      <div>Hello World</div>
    );
};

export default render;
```

How can I write the same using ES6 Classes ?  Or any other solution is available to do this separation ?

I have got the ES6 code something like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Template from './template.jsx';

export default DetailElement extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
    // some code
  }
};
DetailElement.prototype.render = Template;
```

Yes this is working.

Comment: I am not getting question. Do you want to convert your ES 5 code to ES 6? Or do you want to render your ES 6 code into ES 5 code?

Comment: I just want to convert the above code into ES6

Comment: felix-kling I have updated the question. I want to know any other solution for doing this like using react-template and the question is more specific to reactjs

Comment: There is nothing specific to React. An ES6 class is an ES6 class, where you `extend Component` or not. Personally I'd recommend to simply not do it anyway. Keep the logic together.

Comment: @FelixKling I have many layouts  but the logic is same so I want to keep the logic separate. Please note that this is not a duplicate question since It will be helpful to get  a solution to separate the logic and  presentation in react!

Comment: *"I have many layouts but the logic is same so I want to keep the logic separate."* That sounds like you should move this logic into a separate component then. *"since It will be helpful to get a solution to separate the logic and presentation in react!"* Fair enough, though I can't believe something like this hasn't been asked before. Anyways, the whole point of React to keep logic and presentation together.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can do it your template code is like a functional comoponent basically it is a function that returns jsx. You just need to render your template in your DetailElement class

```
import React from 'react';
import Template from './template.jsx';

class DetailElement extends React.Component{
  render = Template
};

export default DetailElement;
```

here is an example I created [codepen link](https://codepen.io/anuprai11894/pen/eBzrqV)
now is a es6 class feature that you can define class property outside class or babel transformer that you need to check

Comment: `render : Template` It will not work!   but `render =Template;` will work

Answer (score 1):

Use something like stateless function to define the `JSX` out of your component.

```js
const HTML = (props) => <div> Hello {props.name}!</div>


class A extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return <HTML name="Joe"/>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<A/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I don't need to use  `react-template`. I just need to separate the jsx part into a separate file

Comment: That is what `react-template` does.

Comment: `JSX` is the HTML inside React. `react-templates` takes the HTML out of your react component

Comment: Yes react-templates is having its own syntax. I don't like that. But it will support Es6 also.. let me try Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But your solution will not help as we need to pass a new set of props to the component and it become a separate component. The logic need to set a lot of props and  state

Comment: You don't really need to pass props if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

here is how the ES6 React looks like

```
import * as React from 'react'
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){

    return (<div className="some class name">
                Hello World
            </div>
          )
  }
}

export default SomeComponent;


//import will look like

import SomeComponent from "./SomeComponent";
```

Detail Element will be something like this

```
import * as React from 'react'
import SomeComponent from "./SomeComponent";

class DetailElement extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){

    return (<div className="some classes">
               <SomeComponent/> 
            </div>
          )
  }
}

export default DetailElement;
```

Not Sure about es6 classes but you can write a function outside react component something like this

```
export const somefun = (parameter1)=> {
  return (<div>{parameter1} </div> )
}
```

then call function in render method

```
render(){

    return (<div className="some class name">
                {somefun()}
            </div>
          )
   }
```

Comment: I need to write the render function in a separate file and import this into the ES6 class file.  I need to know exactly how to use the outside render function inside the component class to render the component

Answer (score 0):

You have to import Component from 'react' and extend it to class.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Template from './template.jsx';

export class  DetailElement extends Component{

  render(){ 
       return(
         <Template></Template>
          );
}
}
```